# behave cannot find class

Tags: python, python-behave

I am new to Python, and am trying [`behave`](https://behave.readthedocs.io/en/stable/) for the first time.  If it matters, I am using VSCode as my editor, and run `behave` from the VSCode terminal.

My project is setup like this:

```
payz
  features
    tuples.feature
    steps
      toople.py
  toople.py
```

`toople.py` contains:

```
from dataclasses import dataclass


@dataclass
class Toople:
    x: float = 0
    y: float = 0
    z: float = 0
    w: float = 0

    def is_point(self) -> bool:
        return self.w == 1.0

    def is_vector(self) -> bool:
        return self.w == 0.0
```

The feature contains:

```
Feature: Tuples, Vectors, and Points

  Scenario: A tuple with w=1.0 is a point
    Given a ← tuple(4.3, -4.2, 3.1, 1.0)
    Then a.x = 4.3
    And a.y = -4.2
    And a.z = 3.1
    And a.w = 1.0
    And a is a point
    And a is not a vector
```

The feature steps has this defined:

```
from behave import *
from toople import *


@given('a ← tuple(4.3, -4.2, 3.1, 1.0)')
def step_impl(context):
    context.a = Toople(x=4.3, y=-4.2, z=3.1, w=1.0)
```

running `behave` from the CLI fails with this error:

```
          context.a = Toople(x=4.3, y=-4.2, z=3.1, w=1.0)
                      ^^^^^^
      NameError: name 'Toople' is not defined
```

from the python shell, it works fine:

```
 ~/src/payz | on main !2 ?2  python                                                                                                                                            1 err | at 07:39:15 PM 
Python 3.11.0 (main, Oct 25 2022, 18:01:25) [GCC 9.4.0] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> from toople import *
>>> a = Toople(x=4.3,y=2.2,z=3.3,w=1.0)
>>> print(a)
Toople(x=4.3, y=2.2, z=3.3, w=1.0)
>>> print(a.is_point())
True
>>> print(a.is_vector())
False
>>>
```

`Toople` is on purpose to avoid any clases with the builtin `Tuple`.

I have `PYTHONDONTWRITEBYTECODE=1` in my environment, in an attempt to rule out any caching (`__pycache__`) issues.

I have changed the class file and saved it in between trying `behave`, and don't see any behavior change.

I had these tests at least partially passing, and then decided to try to rename the class to `Tuple`.  That failed, so I tried undoing that change, which is when I started experiencing this failure.  I have seen the `Given` pass before, so, I'm not seeing what I broke.

How do I debug this? ...and/or...fix this so the feature passes?

Comment: I made no progress and switched my project to using `pytest`.

Comment: code editor and calling environments generally do not matter, you do not need to include them in your question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you are naming two different files with the same name, and that produces this error.

Try to rename the dataclass file to `toople_dataclass.py` and in your steps file write this:

```
from behave import *

from toople_dataclass import Toople


@given('a ← tuple(4.3, -4.2, 3.1, 1.0)')
def step_impl(context):
    context.a = Toople(x=4.3, y=-4.2, z=3.1, w=1.0)
```

That way works for me.